# In asp.net core 2 - How to navigate to absolute root page

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

From a page within areas I am unable to find a path to the root index page.

This should be a simple ask but I cannot find a solution online.

[image]

All these methods return to the root of the current `Area`.

`<form asp-page="@Url.Content("~/Index")" method="post></form>`

`<form asp-page="/Index" method="post></form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `asp-page`, the current Area is *assumed*. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.2#link-generation-with-razor-pages-and-areas) talks about this a little:

> When the area is not specified, routing depends on the ambient values. The current route values of the current request are considered ambient values for link generation.

In order to clear the area completely, use the following:

```html
<form asp-area="" asp-page="/Index" method="post></form>
```